# Replace video url with video player

Tags: plugins, urls

This is my plugin, this will replace the video shortcode format `[video url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOnqjkJTMaA"][video]` (Requirement is to show the video when a user placed a shortcode like this, in the Add New of admin. So I created this  plugin with standard format http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOnqjkJTMaA.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin
*/
function video_url_format()
{
    $content = get_the_content();
    $pieces = explode('"', $content);
    return $pieces[1];

}
add_action('the_content','video_url_format');

?>
```

As you mention the WordPress will automatically show the videoplayer. But it will not show the player. If I paste a standard URL from YouTube like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOnqjkJTMaA, it also doesn't show the video player. But if I commented out the line `add_action('the_content','video_url_format');` in the plugin, then it will show the video player. So the problem may related to my plugin. Please make some point on it. Help please to complete it.

Comment: WordPress 3.6 will do that without a plugin. Take a look at the current nightly build.

Comment: WordPress has included embedding for youtube videos for a few versions now, i've been out of the WP circle for a while, but it was already there before i went away, there's absolutely no need for plugins when it comes to embedding videos from most of the popular video sites, vimeo, youtube, etc..

Comment: You gotta use some script like jwplayer for that, if you want help with jwplayer I can help.

Comment: @MindZ Update **your question** with further research efforts. Never hide essential information in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be a few problems with your plugin as written.

1. As mentioned in the comments above, WordPress has the built-in ability to automatically embed certain types of media, including YouTube videos, given a URL.  See [the Codex page on Embeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds).  So it's likely that your plugin isn't necessary, at least for a YouTube embed.
2. `the_content` is a [filter hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/), not an [action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/).  So typically you'd use `add_filter()` to filter the post's content.
3. Even if you were to attach your function to a proper action hook, you wouldn't see any output from it.  Your function, as written, `return`s a variable, but `add_action()` ignores your `return` -- [according to the Codex, `add_action()` *always returns* `true`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action).

**Actions** typically either `echo()` content to the screen (well, the response buffer) or modify a variable; **Filters** typically accept one or more variables, and return a (possibly modified) version of that variable.  See [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks) for an in-depth look at the differences.