# Clarification on filters and hooks

Tags: filters, hooks, core

I am about to start my first WordPress project and I have the task of moving customized core code that override the core into separate functions/files (this way it'll be easier to maintain when we upgrade in the future.

I have been doing research and it looks like `add_filter` and `apply_filter` and `do_action` and `add_action` seem to be the way to go. I'm still unsure about how they work though. Are those methods what I use to overwrite core methods? I am confused because `add_filter` uses the word `add` when I feel like it is more on the lines of `replace` or `overwrite` (unless I am misunderstanding)

I just read the first answer to [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fliters-vs-actions-from-a-newbe) (the one about the tacos)

So there were three steps the author used in describing how to use add_filter:

**Step 1:** a static value for the $taco variable

`<?php $taco = 'chicken'; ?>`

**Step 2:**

```
    <?php
    $taco = apply_filters( 'get_taco', 'chicken' );
    ?>
```

**Step 3:**

```
    <?php
    add_filter( 'get_taco', 'my_special_order' );
    function my_special_order( $content ) {
        return 'shredded beef';
    }
    ?>
```

So in this situation is the `apply_filter` just creating a dynamic method on the fly and making it return the `chicken` string? Or is the assumption here that there is a core WordPress method called `get_taco` and that using `apply_filter` would help in overriding whatever the original functionality was?

Also, can you only `apply_filter` something that you've `add_filter`ed? In other words, would `apply_filter('get_taco');` not work if I did not define `add_filter('get_taco', 'my_special_order');` AND `function my_special_order ($content) ...` first?

Do I put these filters in my functions.php file? Sorry for bombarding you with questions, I am coming from Ruby on Rails so I'm completely clueless in WordPress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am confused because add_filter uses the word add when I feel like it
>   is more on the lines of replace or overwrite (unless I am
>   misunderstanding)

You are misunderstanding. Both `add_action` and `add_filter` insert function callbacks into a kind of queue. You can add many callbacks to the same hook and they will fire in the sequence added except when a priority is included as the third parameter.

> So in this situation is the apply_filter just creating a dynamic
>   method on the fly and making it return the chicken string?

`apply_filters` -- note the 's'-- does more or less create the filter but usually it is passed a variable not a string and that variable is passed to the callback which then alters it and returns it.

Filter 'slugs' are not the names of WordPress Core functions or methods as a rule though some functions have filters of the same name. For example, `the_content()` calls the `the_content` filter.

Hooks do not usually override whole function, only parts of them, but there are exceptions and near exceptions.

> Also, can you only apply_filter something that you've add_filtered ?

No. The other way around. You can only `add_filter` something that is `apply_filter`ed. You can use `add_filter('whatever','abc');` but nothing at all will happen if there is not an `apply_filter('whatever',...` somewhere.

Pretty much the same applies to `add_action`/`do_action` but actions are for doing things rather than returning values.

Hooks are executed at various times in the page load and at various places in functions and methods. For example, `save_post` executes near the end of [`wp_insert_post`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2950) while `pre_get_posts` executes near the top of the [`get_posts`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L1924) method of the `WP_Query` class. Others execute in [the middle of the page load](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L147) and not in a function or method at all. They execute where ever there is a need (as determined by the developers) to either alter or add information, or run other functions, redirect a page, etc.

## More Information

[Difference Between Filter and Action Hooks?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks)

Comment: So when exactly do these filters/actions get executed? In the beginning/middle/end of the function? Is that something I can control? By adding "hooks" am I just saying "run this function before the function ends but after the code in the function is run"?

Comment: @Edmund : see the edit

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've got it a little bit wrong.

Filters and actions are functions that you "assign" to hooks. In many places WordPress calls `do_action` or `apply_filter` functions. First parameter of these functions is hook name.

So for example when you see

```
do_action('blabla');
```

It means that all actions assigned to 'blabla' hook will be called.

`add_filter` and `add_action` does not overwrite anything. It does exactly what it says - it assigns your function to given hook.

So your Step 2. applies filter `get_taco` to static value `chicken`. And by applies filter I mean it calls all functions assigned to `get_taco` hook.

Your step 3. creates new function `my_special_order` and assigns it to `get_taco` hook. So whenever there is `apply_filter('get_taco')` call, your function will be called.

If there is no filter/action assigned to given hook, nothing will be done.

You can read more on this topic here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API