# How to add_filter/action to comment out CSS generated by admin function?

Tags: admin, filters

So in wp-includes/admin-bar.php there is a function that adds CSS styling to the page:

```
    function _admin_bar_bump_cb() { ?>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    </style>
    <?php
    }
```

I want to comment this out properly (either the function or the contents of the function, either one is fine) but not touch the core code. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
function my_admin_bar_init() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
add_action('admin_bar_init', 'my_admin_bar_init');
```

Add this to your functions.php file. It will disable outputting of these inline styles in `<head>` section but the wp_admin_bar will be still available.

If you would like to disable wp_admin_bar entirely, you can do it like this:

```
remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
```

Comment: no you'd better use `remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 )` moreover he said he want to comment out.

Comment: But he wants to disable these styles, not the admin_bar entirely...

Comment: Hey Krzy, so `admin_bar_init` is what calls `_admin_bar_bump_cb`? And by adding the remove_action, you are removing it from the sequence of functions that `admin_bar_init` runs?

Comment: Well. It's not so easy. In `class-wp-admin-bar.php` file you can find: `if ( empty($header_callback) )
   $header_callback = '_admin_bar_bump_cb'; add_action('wp_head', $header_callback);` on line 56. Then the action `admin_bar_init` is called. So on this hook you can remove function `_admin_bar_bump_cb` from this hook and disable it's output.

Comment: Nice. Sorry this is my first time touching WP. So the point of actions/filters is so that you can customize core functions in specific places by replacing the `add_action` and `add_filter` with your own version?

Comment: You're not replacing anything. You... hmm... You can imagine it like adding your callback function to some queue of callback functions. You can read more on this topic here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103641/clarification-on-filters-and-hooks

Comment: (Actually that's my question, haha) So when you guys say "hooks", you mean the original function is run, and then whatever function you are hooking on to it has the ability to overwrite parts of it?

Comment: No. Hook is name/tag (first parameter of `do_action`/`apply_filter`). Just look into WordPress source code and check what do_action really does. ;)

Comment: Have I solved your problem with my answer or did you mean something else with this question?