# What are the steps + prerequisites for using an add_filter?

Tags: filters

Hey all I'm a WP noob and I have the task of cleaning up the mess other people left when they edited plugin cores. To my understanding, there are such things called filters in WP. I am not sure how to use them though or how they work. For this example below (copied from a tutorial):

```
function remove_footer_admin () {
echo 'Fueled by <a href="http://www.wordpress.org" target="_blank">WordPress</a> | Designed by <a href="http://www.uzzz.net" target="_blank">Uzzz Productions</a> | WordPress Tutorials: <a href="http://www.wpbeginner.com" target="_blank">WPBeginner</a></p>';
}

add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'remove_footer_admin');
```

What is going on? So we are overwriting the `admin_footer_text` function? In this case, it's a function from the admin section. To my current understanding (tell me if I'm wrong please), the admin section has loads of default WP functions that are executed in a certain order. This `add_filter` that uses `remove_footer_admin` will be called as an after hook. So whatever WP functions run before `admin_footer_text` will run accordingly, then `admin_footer_text`, then `remove_footer_admin`, then whatever WP functions that usually run after `admin_footer_text`. Is this correct?

Also, it seems like add_filter can only be added sometimes? I don't get what the conditions are. Could you please explain in what situation I can use it?

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/103641/21376) and what do the answers to that question not explain?

Comment: I still don't get when the filter is run in the context of the function that I am `add_filter`ing to. Is it sort of like adding a few lines of code to that function and running them before the end of the function?

Comment: That's actually a pretty bad example of what a filter should do.  The rule of thumb that I follow is that a filter should `return` something, not `echo` it.  If you want to `echo` something, then use `add_action()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to think of `add_filter` as a way for you to adjust a variable.  It can be used anywhere you see an `apply_filters` in the code.  Typically, you `return` a variable value instead of echoing it out.

Your example would be better written like so:

```
function remove_footer_admin () {
return 'Fueled by <a href="http://www.wordpress.org" target="_blank">WordPress</a> | Designed by <a href="http://www.uzzz.net" target="_blank">Uzzz Productions</a> | WordPress Tutorials: <a href="http://www.wpbeginner.com" target="_blank">WPBeginner</a></p>';
}

add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'remove_footer_admin');
```

And `remove_footer_admin()` would be run when the WP code hits the

```
echo apply_filters( 'admin_footer_text', '<span id="footer-thankyou">' . __( 'Thank you for creating with <a href="http://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a>.' ) . '</span>' );
```

in admin-footer.php...where the second parameter (`<span>` and so forth) is the variable that `apply_filters` is allowing you to modify in this instance.

I wrote a [tutorial on WordPress filters](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/455/wordpress-filters-fundamentals/) that I think might help explain some things.

Comment: Great!!! thanks a lot! I'll check out your tutorial!!