# how to add_filter to non hook function

Tags: functions, filters

the idea is apply some filters if the user select the option in the theme, but i have a problem

i made a function that replace the post_thumbnail_html for a personalized html

then, i create other function that create thumnails for timthumb

i'm trying to apply the add_filter to the timthumb function, but it doesn't work because is not a wordpress hook

can you helpme?

```
function kandombe_theme_thumb($id, $width, $height, $align='') {

        //some code

        $html = '<img class="archive_thumb" src='.$image_url.' width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"/>';

        return $html;

    }

if ($data['speed_lazy_loading']) { 

    function kandombe_lazy_loads( $html ) {

        //some code

        $html = preg_replace( '#<img([^>]+?)src=[\'"]?([^\'"\s>]+)[\'"]?([^>]*)>#', sprintf( '<img${1}src="%s" data-original="${2}"${3} style="display: block;"><noscript><img${1}src="${2}"${3}></noscript>', $placeholder_image ), $html );

    return $html;
    }

add_filter( 'the_content', 'kandombe_lazy_loads');
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'kandombe_lazy_loads');
add_filter( 'kandombe_theme_thumb', 'kandombe_lazy_loads');
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'kandombe_lazy_loads');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this-- `add_filter( 'kandombe_theme_thumb', 'kandombe_lazy_loads');`-- is the line/hook you are talking about.

You don't hook to functions. That is not how it works. Hooks have to be intentionally created with `apply_filters` or `do_action`. Your code would have to be written like this for that to work:

```
function kandombe_theme_thumb($id, $width, $height, $align='') {
    //some code
    $html = apply_filters(
      'kandombe_theme_thumb',
      '<img class="archive_thumb" src='.$image_url.' width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"/>'
    );
    return $html;
}
```

## Related

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103644/21376