# How do filters and hooks really work in PHP

Tags: filters, hooks

How does filters and hooks actually work in WordPress?

I'm asking about something advanced. How is it implemented in PHP? E.g how does it collect all the hooks from the different plugins and "attach" them to the core hooks etc.

Comment: As far as I know there are no 'hooks' or 'filters' in php , there are functions.
Wordpress have special functions that before their executions use a call-back of other functions.

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103641/clarification-on-filters-and-hooks/103644#103644

Comment: @OfirBaruch, I'm pretty sure the OP was referring to their implementation in WordPress, and wasn't suggesting there was some native PHP implementation thereof.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Overview

Basically the "[Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)," which summons Filters and Hooks, consists out of the following functions:

1. [`apply_filters()`](http://queryposts.com/function/apply_filters/) - *execute*
2. [`do_action`](http://queryposts.com/function/do_action/) - *execute*
3. [`apply_filters_ref_array()`](http://queryposts.com/function/apply_filters_ref_array/) - *execute*
4. [`do_action_ref_array()`](http://queryposts.com/function/do_action_ref_array/) - *execute*
5. [`add_filter()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_filter/) - *add to stack*
6. [`add_action()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_action/) - *add to stack*

### Basic Internals

Overall there're a couple of globals (what else in WordPress world) involved:

```
global $wp_filter, $wp_actions, $wp_current_filter, $merged_filters;
```

The first one `$wp_filter` is a global `Array` that holds all filter names as subarrays. Each of those subarrays then holds even more subarrays that are callbacks summoned under a priority array.

### Brief in-depth

So when an *execute* function is called, WordPress searches those globals arrays for the keys with that name. Then the attached callbacks get executed priority after priority. The only thing that happens up front are callbacks attached to the `all` filter.

When you add a callback using `add_action` or `add_filter`, then WordPress first calculates a "unique" ID to not overwrite already attached callbacks.

```
$idx = _wp_filter_build_unique_id($tag, $function_to_add, $priority);
```

Then it adds your callback to the `global $wp_filter` stack:

```
$wp_filter[ $tag ][ $priority ][ $idx ] = array(
    'function'      => $function_to_add,
    'accepted_args' => $accepted_args
);
```

As you can see the main sub array is the `$tag` (or action/filter name), then everything is summoned under a specific priority, and then the "unique" callback/ID string gets used as key.

Later, when a filter gets called - happening with the `$tag`/action-/filter-name - the array gets searched and the callbacks get called. As it is using `call_user_func_array` it doesn't really matter how many arguments are attached. WordPress resolves that by itself.

```
foreach ( (array) current( $wp_filter[ $tag ] ) as $the_ )
{
    call_user_func_array(
        $the_['function'], 
        array_slice(
            $args, 
            0, 
            (int) $the_['accepted_args']
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: don't forget that as it's going through the callbacks, it orders the execution of multiple callbacks on the same hook using their "priority", which is set (optionally) with add_action() and apply_filters() and defaults to 10.

Comment: @TomAuger Please feel free to add any additional notes and edits to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Hooks** are included in both the WordPress core files and some parent themes files. They enable you to hook in content in a specific location in the file.

An example is the wp_head hook in WordPress. You can use this hook in your child theme to add content in that location'

Example:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_content_to_head');
function add_content_to_head() {
echo 'Your Content';
}
```

Some premium themes also include [action hooks](http://my.studiopress.com/docs/hook-reference/) which you can use in a child theme to do the same thing. Here's a [visual map](http://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/) which includes all the the action hooks and the position they output your content in the Genesis theme framework.

Example:

```
add_action('genesis_header', 'add_content_to_header');
function add_content_to_header() {
echo 'Your Content';
}
```

Here's what the hook looks like if you opened the header.php file in the Genesis theme framework:

```
do_action( 'genesis_header' );
```

Here's a [list of WordPress hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) you can use in many ways.

**Filters** enable you to modify the output of an existing function and is included in both the WordPress core files and some parent theme frameworks like Genesis.

Here's a [list of the filters](http://my.studiopress.com/docs/filter-reference/) you can use with the Genesis Design Framework

Here's a list of the [filters included in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)

Here's an example of how you can use a filter in a theme framework like Genesis:

```
add_filter( 'comment_author_says_text', 'custom_comment_author_says_text' );
function custom_comment_author_says_text() {
return 'author says';
}
```

The above code can be used in a child theme to modify the author says text in your comments. It works in any theme.

Here's another example which customizes the length of excerpts to 50 words:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'change_excerpt_length' );
function change_excerpt_length($length) {
return 50; 
}
```

You'll find the the_excerpt() function in the [wp-includes/post-template.php file.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/post-template.php#L254)

Here's what it looks like:

```
  function the_excerpt() {
        echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt());
}
```

You can also use hooks and filters in plugins to do exactly the same thing and the code won't be lost when you update the parent theme or WordPress.

Basically, hooks and filters enable you to customize and modify both WordPress and your parent theme without editing the core WordPress files or your parent theme files.

Its significantly easier to customize a child theme when the parent theme framework includes hooks and filters because you never need to edit the parent themes template files. This way you can safely change themes as well.

Comment: This is a great general overview of hooks and filters, but I'm afraid totally misses the OP's question, which is about the internals of how hooks work and how WordPress creates, stores and processes them. Great answer; you should probably link to your tutorial on WP Sites.

Comment: O.k I'll delete it. My bad as i should have read the question better but thought the answers already given would be easier for beginners to understand if they knew the basic first.

Comment: Brad, I undeleted it as I think it might be useful to have that info here as well. If you don´t  agree, just mention/ping me here and I´ll remove it again.