# Issues with title-tag and document_title_parts

Tags: functions, theme-development, filters, hooks, title

`Wordpress version 4.5.1`

I'm trying to dynamically update page titles on a particular template. After lots of digging and learning about the `wp_title()` changes, I'm attempting to use `document_title_parts`. However, I can't get the filter to run at all.

I'm in a child theme, `functions.php`:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
//add_filter("after_setup_theme", function(){ add_theme_support("title-tag"); });

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function( $title )
{
    error_log('here');
    return $title;

}, 10, 1 );
```

I've tried both variations of adding theme support as shown above, but watching my log, nothing appears on page reload. That `error_log` was working with other functions (such as `wp_title`), so the error logging is working.

I've also tried `pre_get_document_title`, which does fire on page load, though I'm unable to get it to actually change the title.

So! I'm either using the filter wrong, didn't set up my theme correctly, or something else I'm unaware of. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*edit to add more detail*

Attempting an init function, but that also isn't working: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6db5af892a4cf4fb029655167d7002a4

Also, while I've removed any reference to `<title>` from `header.php`, the actual site title is still showing up in the source.

Comment: Why did you commented out this line `//add_filter("after_setup_theme", function(){ add_theme_support("title-tag"); });` ? It is correct use of adding theme support.

Comment: @Sumit I tried both the commented out version and the active version.

Comment: Maybe try adding `add_theme_support()` function in an [init hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init). Another thing is to ensure that you overwrite your `header.php` file to _not_ have an html `<title>` tag.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Just tried that, still nothing. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6db5af892a4cf4fb029655167d7002a4

Comment: @hookedonwinter And you're sure that there's no `<title>` tags in your `header.php`? Maybe try replacing `10` with `PHP_MAX_INT`. Also, the passed parameter is an array instead of a string value.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Correct - no reference to title at all in header.php. Maybe this being a child theme has some effect, and the parent is winning? Also, made the PHP_MAX_INT change, still no joy.

Comment: @hookedonwinter Could be - you could modify your parent theme to test that theory and remove your changes once verified.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I'll try that. Thanks for the assistance! I'll post an update when I've figured it out / exhausted my options.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran your filter in my development area. It didn't work. Then I switched off the Yoast SEO plugin, which I knew was also messing with the page title. Then it worked. So my suggestion would be another plugin is messing with it.

In the case of Yoast, it was a filter call to `pre_get_document_title` returning non empty. In that case [`wp_get_document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/) is short circuited and the rest of the function, including the `documents_title_parts` filter, is not evaluated, as you can see from the first lines of code:

```
$title = apply_filters( 'pre_get_document_title', '' );
if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
    return $title;
    }
```

So, I took your filter and changed the hook to `pre_get_document_title`. It didn't work. Then I changed the priority to a higher level than the same filter in Yoast. Then it worked. So, I don't know about your set-up, but I suggest you give this a try:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', function( $title )
  {
    error_log('here');
    return $title;
  }, 999, 1 );
```

Comment: You got it! I found the same thing, and deactivated Yoast. I just reactivated and used your priority and it worked. THANK YOU!

Comment: A bit more on hooks here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109869/how-do-filters-and-hooks-really-work-in-php/109889#109889

Comment: From my site, the `pre_get_document_title` priority **15** is enough.

Answer (score 8):

After some experimenting I came to the following suggestion: could it be, that  the `<title>` tag is "hard coded" inside your parent theme's `header.php`? If that is the case, you could try to remove the `<title>` tag from your child theme's `header.php` (copy your parent's `header.php` into your child theme folder) and then add the theme support back through the `functions.php`:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

I'll try to explain what lead me to this suggestion: I tried as you and others suggested – but it turned out that I found **two `<title>` tags** in the source code. The first one had the *standard title*, the second one the *modified title*. But (of course) in the browser title bar I could only see the default title.

I then checked the `header.php` of the parent theme I used (twentyfourteen) and the `<title>` tag was indeed hard coded inside that template like this:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

After I removed it, I added the following code to the child theme's `functions.php` and it worked:

```
/**
 * Theme support added
 */

function add_theme_support_child() {

    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_theme_support_child', 11 );


/**
 * Change the title of a page
 * 
 */

function change_title_for_a_template( $title ) {

// Check if current page template is 'template-homepage.php'
// if ( is_page_template( 'template-homepage.php' ) ) {

    // change title parts here
    $title['title'] = 'My Title'; 
    $title['tagline'] = 'My fancy tagline'; // optional
    $title['site'] = 'example.org'; //optional

// }

return $title; 

}

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'change_title_for_a_template', 10, 1 );
```

So it basically also worked before removing the `<title>` tag from the template – only that there were then **two** `<title>` tags of which the later was ignored. Could this be the same problem with your theme?

**Since wp 4.4.0 however the `<title>` tag is created dynamically** by the function `_wp_render_title_tag()` which basically calls another function `wp_get_document_title()` and wraps the html tags around the result. Long story short: if your theme's `header.php` is missing the `<title>` tag, chances are that you can override the title directly through `pre_get_document_title` or `document_title_parts` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266520/wordpress-4-4-wp-title-filter-takes-no-effect-on-the-title-tag):

1) change the title directly:

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_the_title');
function change_the_title() {
    return 'The expected title';
}
```

2) filtering the title parts:

```
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'filter_title_part');
function filter_title_part($title) {
    return array('a', 'b', 'c');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Having read your post from top to botom and bottom to top, you have in all probabilty a filter that is passing a title through the `pre_get_document_title` filter. The clue here the following statement:

> I've also tried `pre_get_document_title`, which does fire on page load,

Looking at the [soure code for `wp_get_document_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/), we see the following code:

```
$title = apply_filters( 'pre_get_document_title', '' );
if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
    return $title;
}
```

What this means is, whenever a non empty value is passes through the `pre_get_document_title` filter, the `wp_get_document_title()` function will return whatever value that was passed via the `pre_get_document_title` filter. It this case, the `document_title_separator` filter and the `document_title_parts` filter will never be executed as these only run after the `pre_get_document_title` filter.

Looking at what you said a bit further on:

> ...though I'm unable to get it to actually change the title.

you definitely have a `pre_get_document_title` filter with authority which is overriding your instance of the same filter, and because of this filter, the function return whatever is passed to it which results in your `document_title_parts` filter not being executed.

What you will need to do is is to use either `grep` or a good editor and search your entire `wp-content` folder for that `pre_get_document_title` filter. Once you located that filter, you can take it from there to remove that filter and replace it with your own

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, searching all of wp-content for `document_title_parts` or `pre_get_document_title` returns 0 results. I'm using SublimeText 2 to search all of wp-content...

Comment: This really beats me. It is really strange that one filter in a function fires correctly and the filter after that does not. Try clearing all caches and reinstal WordPress if you are sure it is not a plugin or your theme. What happens on a vanilla install with a bundled theme, what happens if you directly alter the parent theme. This is unfortunately as far as I can help with the info given. If you have any extra info, file an [edit] so we can assist you in solving this

Comment: @PieterGoosen When the first filter returns non empty the function is short circuited and the second filter is not evaluated.

Comment: @cjbj yes, correct, that is what I said in my answer, the issue is what. As the OP said, he can't find a filter on `pre_get_document_title`, what would have totally explained why the second filter would not fire. This leaves the `pre_get_document_title` filter empty, which means the other two filters in the function must fire, but they don't. It leaves me to conclude a corrupt Wordpress core.

Comment: Except that I got that filter to work easily.

Comment: @cjbj yes, it works for me as well. The OP's code works in theory (*as we all have tested and see*), but it does not for him, this is the whole reason behind the question. To be very technical here, this question is off topic as the issue is localized, this is an issue that we cannot replicate

Comment: But it's still a nice puzzle, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, guys. Turns out it was just Yoast. I appreciate all the brain power!

Answer (score 2):

If the parent theme does not declare support for `title-tag` you can do it like this in child theme

```
/**
 * Theme support should be added on `after_setup_theme`
 */
function add_theme_support_child() {

    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_theme_support_child', 11 );
```

Filter `document_title_parts` expected return type array, like this, be sure to change the if condition as per your requirements, or remove it completely to change the title throughout the site just for testing if it works.

```
/**
 * Change title of a page conditionally
 * 
 * @return $title - type array
 * $title['title'] - Page Title
 * $title['tagline'] - Site Tagline
 */
function change_title_for_a_template( $title ) {

    // Check if current page template is 'template-homepage.php'
    if ( is_page_template( 'template-homepage.php' ) ) {
        $title['title'] = 'Changed title for a template';
    }

    return $title;

}

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'change_title_for_a_template' );
```

Can you try thes two functions?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it, removing the if statement to make it more broad, and I added some error logging to see what's up. [Here's the code.](https://gist.github.com/pjhoberman/95cd08ba4eef655ebe7ca89541a50990). Only `add_theme_support_child` is logged.