# admin_notices is not working inside function

Tags: actions, notices

I am creating a plugin . But when I trying to call the `add_action('admin_notices','my_test_notice_1');` inside a function its not working.

I need to call the `add_action('admin_notices','my_test_notice_1')` inside my function . How can I do it. - Thanks advance for your answer.

```
<?php 
/*
* Plugin Name: Test Plugin
* Description: Testin the plugin description
* Version:     1.0.0
* Author:      Shafiq Suhag
* Author URI:  https://roobnet.com/
* License:     GPLv2 or later
* License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
* Text Domain: rsms
* Domain Path: /languages
*/

function test_plugin_admin_menu()
{        
    add_menu_page(__('Testing Page ', 'rses'), __('Testing Page', 'rses'), 'activate_plugins', 'testing_plugin', 'testing_plugin_cb_function','dashicons-businessman');
    function testing_plugin_cb_function(){

        // Admin Notice 2 : This is not working 
        add_action('admin_notices', 'admin_notice_2');
        function admin_notice_2(){
            echo '<h1> admin_notice_1  is printed on the page  </h1>';
        }
    }

    // Admin Notice 1 - This is working
    add_action('admin_notices', 'admin_notice_1');
    function admin_notice_1(){
        echo '<h1> admin_notice_1  is printed on the page  </h1>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_admin_menu');
```

Comment: You are hooking "admin_notice_2()" function inside callback of "add_menu_page()". That is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is happening because of hook firing sequence. Hooks actually get loaded from an array[(have a look)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109869/how-do-filters-and-hooks-really-work-in-php) where `admin_notices` executes before `add_menu_page` gets called.

Now to show you message in your admin page you can check `global $pagenow` and the *page* GET variable by `$_GET['page']` with an `if` condition and print your message. Like below-

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'test_plugin_admin_menu' ); 
function test_plugin_admin_menu () {
    add_menu_page(
        __('Testing Page ', 'rses'),
        __('Testing Page', 'rses'),
        'activate_plugins',
        'testing_plugin',
        'testing_plugin_cb_function',
        'dashicons-businessman'
    );
}

function testing_plugin_cb_function () {
    // Do your magic here
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'admin_notice_1' );
function admin_notice_1 () {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( 'admin.php' === $pagenow && 'testing_plugin' === $_GET['page'] ) {
        echo '<h1> admin_notice_1  is printed on the page  </h1>';
    }
}
```

By the way, nested functions are quite a bad thing, so I'm putting here a **refactored version of your code**. Please test it before putting it in production.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.for your answer.

Comment: You welcome! Anyway, as the author of the question, if the answer fulfilled your purpose then you should accept the answer by clicking the **tick or check** mark on the left of it! @ShafiqulIslam