# How does add_action 'comment_post' work?

Tags: php, comments, actions

I found an example how to [How To AJAX-ify WordPress Comments](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ajaxify-wordpress-comments/). I tweak it little bit and so far everything works fine but I want to understand the code.

1. Where did the arguments `$comment_ID, $comment_status` come from? I cannot find any reference about the arguments that are available. Can I use any other? More importantly do I have to use above names and what are the values for $comment_status?
2. Do I have to call `wp_notify_moderator()` and `wp_notify_postauthor()` functions or they would be called by WordPress when inserting the comment into database?
3. I don't understand syntax of these two lines `$commentdata=&get_comment($comment_ID, ARRAY_A);
               $post=&get_post($commentdata['comment_post_ID'])` what does the `&` does and what is `ARRAY_A`

Could some one answer my questions about below function that is called from this action. I know that `2` means that `ajaxify_comments` can accept two arguments but where did they come from? What about the names? Values? Possible values?

```
add_action('comment_post', 'ajaxify_comments',20, 2);
```

and the function code is like

```
function ajaxify_comments($comment_ID, $comment_status){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
        //If AJAX Request Then

        switch($comment_status){
            case '0':
                echo "success1";                        // send a message to ajax
                wp_notify_moderator($comment_ID);       // notify moderator of unapproved comment
                break;
            case '1':                                   // approved comment
                echo "success2";                            // send a message to ajax
                $commentdata=&get_comment($comment_ID, ARRAY_A);
                $post=&get_post($commentdata['comment_post_ID']);
                wp_notify_postauthor($comment_ID, $commentdata['comment_type']);
                break;
            default:
                echo "error";                           // send a message to ajax
         }
         exit(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: the easiest way to see how an action works is to look for its related `do_action` in source. search for `'comment_post'` in `wp-includes/comment.php`.

Comment: This might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/103641/21376