# How to find out if an wp-admin action edited a file?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, apc

I want to create a small plugin to automatically purge the APC opcode cache after specific actions in the Wordpress admin interface. This is necessary if e.g. apc.stat is set to 0, as a change to a file then doesn't reset its cache value in the opcode cache and so calls will use the old, cached, out-of-date file. Total debug nightmare if you forget to clear the cache manually.

**Is there an easy way to find out if an action edited/changed a file?**

I could manually check if is_admin and POST and file is e.g. theme-editor.php, but this seems like a not very nice hack that is bound to miss some things.

Answer (score 1):

[The system redirects after an update with `updated=true`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/theme-editor.php#L89).  You could check for that `GET` parameter on the `load-theme-editor.php` hook, something like:

```
add_action(
  'load-theme-editor.php',
  function() {
    if (isset($_GET['updated']) && true == $_GET['updated']) {
      // clear the cache
    }
  }
);
```

I looked for more specific hooks and couldn't find any, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, seems I should read up on this hook stuff to really understand how this works. I wrote a followup question on which other actions can change files here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/121009/6495

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103644/21376

Comment: If this solved the question please [mark it as "Accepted"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Look for the check mark on the left.

Comment: Sure, as soon as I tried it and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should set APC to not check file updates only on deployment environment. If you give access to change the code then it is not a deployment environment.

In general what you are trying to do violate a basic monitoring rule - a software/device should not monitor itself, as it might get into a condition in which the monitoring can not be done. In your case you will find it hard to fix your monitoring code if there is a bug in it.

A better solution is to have an external program which monitors file changes under the wordpress root directory and clears the cache when it is detected. It will be much smaller , more reliable and easier to maintain then what you are trying to do here. (since you have APC I assume you have your own VPS and can hook to the file change notification service which all OSs has now)