# Which actions can update/change .php files?

Tags: wp-admin, filesystem

As a followup to my question "[How to find out if an wp-admin action edited a file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/120992/6495)" I now could use a list of actions and files that can actually cause an update or change to .php-files in a default Wordpress installation on the file system.

Right now I think of:

- Adding themes
- Editing themes
- Adding plugins
- Updating plugins
- Updating core

Did I miss something?

Comment: "Updating Themes", but this question is pretty broad and there is no telling what a theme or plugin might do internally... and then there is (s)FTP, ssh, etc.

Comment: s_ha_dum is right. Any of the actions you listed above can be done from backend **or** directly from the file-system and there is no way (from PHP) to attach a trigger to a filesystem change event, so you won't be able to immediately detect a change over this way.

Comment: Added "in a default Wordpress installation" to my question to clarify.