# Using hooks to place content in theme dynamically

Tags: filters, actions

Alright, so I think I may be getting a little too complicated on this, but I basically want to know if this is possible. I am using a content slide function where I display some thumbnails within the main content area, but after the #container ID, I need to put almost the same information, and a little bit more, and I thought maybe I could do a custom action hook for this.

so I have this

```
<?php

function the_maps() {
while( $maps->have_posts() ) : $maps->the_post();

    $content .= "<div class='m-all t-1of3 dw-1of3 cf map'>";
        $content .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="trigger-overlay" onClick="return false;">';
            $content .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'featured-map', $attr );
        $content .= '</a>';
        $content .= "<h2><a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</a></h2>";       
    $content .= "</div>";                       

    // ADD CUSTOM HOOK HERE TO DISPLAY ADDITIONAL DATA AT A SPECIFIC PART OF THE THEME
    // stuck here

    $footer_content = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'featured-map', $attr );    
    // This is where I would like to use an action or hook to push the $footer_content on the footer.php file
    add_action( 'after_wp_footer', 'slide_content', 10, 1);
    do_action( 'after_wp_footer', $footer_content );    


endwhile;

}

function slide_content( $arg ) {
// stuck here too
}
```

So at the end of it all, I want the html to look like this. It's dumbed down, but hopefully you'll get the picture.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class='m-all t-1of3 dw-1of3 cf map'>
            <a href="permalink">
                <img src="image" alt="image">
            </a>
            <h2>title</h2>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /#container -->

    <!-- extra information here for slider function -->
        <img src="image" alt="image">


</body>
```

This is based off the following demo: http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/index7.html

I am trying to push myself more on wordpress, and just wanted to know if any WP experts would know if this can be done.

I am sure this are many techniques to accomplish this, but I just wanted to know if I could push content to a hook or function in my theme files

TIA!

Comment: Why would you add an action immediately before you run the action?

Comment: I know, it doesn't make any sense at all. I am just trying to wrap my head around the wordpress actions, so I just need a little direction on, if what I described above could actually happen. I can call the add_action('wp_footer', 'my_funct', 10) where you pointed out my error all day, but if I cannot pass variables or an output to it, then it will not work.

Comment: You may have a duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/135254/21376

Answer (score 1):

If you're the parent theme Developer, you can add the hook in your parent themes file and then use it in a custom function in your child theme.

**1. Add Hook To Parent Themes File**

```
<?php do_action( 'after_wp_footer' ); ?>
```

**2. Create Function For New Hook in Parent Theme**

```
function create_after_footer_hook() {

do_action('after_wp_footer');

}
```

**3. Add Hook In Custom Function Using Child Theme**

```
function your_function_name() {

echo 'Replace this entire line of code with your code to do stuff';
}
add_action('after_wp_footer', 'your_function_name');
```