# what is do_action(); in wordpress?

Tags: theme-development, filters, hooks

Sorry for making duplicate Topic but it is very important to me because i don't understand this topic by looking other related topics.
Actually i am in process to build a WordPress theme and i am working on it, when i look into other themes source codes usually i find this code.

etc etc.

and i understand its something related to do_action();

So my question is that why we use this function in wordpress? and what is the job of this function and can we have a benefit of using this code on every starting and ending html tags in theme?

Thanks in Advance,
Regards aran

Comment: sorry the php code is hidden from the question, its <?php do_action('before_head');?> <?php swift_before_content();?> etc etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between do\_action and add\_action](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120339/difference-between-do-action-and-add-action) and [What does do_action() function do in wordpress?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145892/what-does-do-action-function-do-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually used by WP to allow plugin developers change WP behavior. You can make your code flexible using do_action so other plugin/theme developers or simply yourself can change behavior of your code.

For example imagine you have a WP loop in a theme framework. You would like to add breadcrumb at the top of it, here is the simplest method:

```
...
<?php print_breadcrumb(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
...
```

But this way plugin developers or site authors require to edit print_breadcrumb() at functions.php to add their own breadcrumbs. Better way is using do_action()

```
...
<?php do_action('breadcrumb') ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
...
```

Now you can add this in functions.php to get same behavior:

```
add_action('breadcrumb', 'print_breadcrumb');
```

Now a plugin author may override your code by:

```
add_action('breadcrumb', 'their_own_breadcrumb');
```