# Returning or use form data using a hook?

Tags: customization, actions

I have built a plugin that allows a user to submit forms to a third party API via an API call. I'm wondering if it's possible to add in a hook right before (or after) the data gets sent to the third party, and return it for use in a function.

Ideally, a user could define there own function and hook into the hook I have set, grab the data and use it how they please, or manipulate it before it gets sent off to the API.

```
if(!empty($p['form_data']))
    {
    parse_str($p['form_data'], $fd);
    if(!empty($fd['list-id']))
        {
        // Create and store the variables needed to add a new subscriber        
        $email  = false;
        $lid  = empty($fd['list-id'];
        $api  = 'api_key';
        $mv = array();
        $optin  = 'true';

// Add custom hook, to capture user submitted data
do_action( 'get_form_data', $p['form_data'] );
        }
    }
```

And then ideally the user could write a function to use the data (basic example).

```
function catch_user_data( $data ) {
    $user_email = $data['email'];
    update_user_meta( '1' , 'user_email', $user_email );
}
add_action( 'get_form_data' , 'catch_user_data' );
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here as the data doesn't get updated on form submission. Is the hook written wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow users to "manipulate it before it gets sent off to the API" I would suggest using a filter instead of an action.

```
if ( ! empty( $p['form_data'] ) ) {
    parse_str( $p['form_data'], $fd );
    if ( ! empty( $fd['list-id'] ) ) {
        // Create and store the variables needed to add a new subscriber        
        $email  = false;
        $lid  = empty( $fd['list-id'] );
        $api  = 'api_key';
        $mv = array();
        $optin  = 'true';

        // Add custom hook, to capture user submitted data
        $p['form_data'] = apply_filters( 'get_form_data', $p['form_data'] );
    }
}
```

This will be the code that enables users to manipulate this data.

```
function catch_user_data( $data ) {
    $user_email = $data['email'];
    update_user_meta( '1' , 'user_email', $user_email );
    return str_replace( 'find-something', 'replace-it', $data );
}
add_filter( 'get_form_data' , 'catch_user_data' );
```

More reading:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters
http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Action
http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Filter

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am getting confused with all the actions and filters! I should go back and re-read the sections in the codex.

Comment: @EHerman : this might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103644/21376