# How should I use a plugin function as a hook?

Tags: plugins, hooks

I'm using [Expire Password plugin](https://github.com/shrkey/expirepassword), an open source plugin to expire users. It actually lets you expire users from the Users admin page, individually.

I need to create a new user from a front-end form, which is already implemented, but expiring its password. So I thought there should be a way to call that plugin function to do that, instead of clicking on the Users admin page "Expire Password" link.

Comment: This may be more of a PHP question than anything, which makes it off topic here, but you can call a plugin function like any other function that occurs in a PHP application. And you can't use any function like a hook. It doesn't work that way. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103644/21376

Comment: This is about how to properly do that on Wordpress...

Comment: Other than the methods discussed in the answer I linked to, this has nothing to do with WordPress. If you understand PHP you know how to do it. Either you are asking for help with a plugin, or with PHP, or you are asking a question that already has an answer. This question can be closed for any of those reasons. Maybe you should consider editing your question so that it is more clear.