# Get audio metadata on file upload

Tags: plugin-development, loop, uploads, post-meta

I am trying to fetch all audio metadata when I upload a file.

This all happens in a plugin, and I currently use the `add_attachment` action to trigger my custom function :

```
// link
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'add_metadata' );

// Definition
public function get_metadata( $post_ID ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_ID );
    var_dump( $post );
    var_dump( wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_ID ) ); 
}
```

The `$post` contains a lot of information, `object(WP_Post)#375 (24) { ... }`, but the `wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_ID )` is `""`.

I suspect that all the metadata is not generated at the time of the upload, but still I am able to fetch them inside `The Loop` on a custom page with the following code :

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    );    
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $post ) { 
            $attachment_metadatas = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post->ID );
            echo '<pre>' . var_export( $attachment_metadatas, true ) . '</pre>';
        }
    }
endwhile;
```

Do you have an idea of what I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the data with a filter:

```
add_filter('wp_update_attachment_metadata', 'grab_meta_data');
function grab_meta_data($data, $post_id) {
    // inspect $data here
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot :) I may need to understand more the difference between a filter and an action.

Comment: @Nobe4 : [actions and filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103644/21376)