# How to read out the excerpt length (for if-condition)

Tags: count, excerpt

I'm trying to do is the following.
**If the excerpt length is shorter than 30 charakters**, than do..

```
<?php if ( get_the_excerpt() <= 30 AND has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
   <div></div>
<?php else : ?>
   <div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it seems like that's not the way to read out the length.
I was playing around with some definitions that I found like:

```
<?php if ( the_excerpt() <= 30 AND has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<?php if ( $count($the_excerpt) <= 30 AND has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<?php if ( excerpt_length($count) <= 30 AND has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
```

..but I'm helpless. So..you kind guys. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more PHP as you need to use [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) to count the amount of words in the excerpt. Just note, to be safe, if you allow any tags in the excerpt, you would want to use `strip_tags()` to remove html tags to avoid incorrect word counts.

### EXAMPLE:

```
echo str_word_count( strip_tags( get_the_excerpt() ) );
```

If you need to display wordcount on the front end, you can also wrap the above in `number_format_i18n()` to return the integer value according to locale set

```
echo number_format_i18n( str_word_count( strip_tags( get_the_excerpt() ) ) );
```

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is basic PHP:

```
$exc = get_the_excerpt();
// var_dump($exc);
$exc = strlen($exc);
// var_dump($exc);
if ( $exc <= 30 AND has_post_thumbnail() ) {

} else {

}
```

You need to count the string's characters before trying to compare the string to an integer. PHP's `strlen()` does that.

However, you also misunderstand a few things...

```
if ( the_excerpt() <= 30 AND has_post_thumbnail() ) :
```

`the_excerpt()` prints content. All that will do is `echo` the excerpt to the screen. There is no data "captured" to operate on.

```
if ( $count($the_excerpt) <= 30 AND has_post_thumbnail() )
```

The leading `$` makes this a function. While you can create a [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) in PHP, I doubt you have. Without the `$`, `count()` will just return `1` with a string. It doesn't count the characters.

```
if ( excerpt_length($count) <= 30 AND has_post_thumbnail() )
```

[`excerpt_length`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length) doesn't work that way. In fact, it isn't even a function. It is a filter.

I'd suggest that if you are going to be hacking your site, get familiar with the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/docs.php) and the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/), and stop trying to guess at functions, infer from other languages, or just make things up. [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103644/21376) may be helpful too.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for this explanation!! I know I have to learn more about all this. even more now that you mention the points, identifying a function, filter and so on. Never thought i I would be hacking this deep into the site :D Thanks for the links! This will be my evening read :)