# WP plugin calls for custom pages

Tags: plugins, customization, templates

I'm trying to create a custom landing page for my site. I am using wordpress because of the SEO plugins they offer. Mind you I'm not an expert so this might be an obvious question (please be gentle)

How would I be able to include a plugin like Yoast to a custom page template? In general, how what is the best way to include plugins into your custom pages? If someone could point me in the right direction or perhaps provide some documentation for me to read, that'd be great.

Thanks for the help.

[EDIT]

I was asked for clarification so hopefully I am able to clarify my question a bit. I want to include my wordpress plugin in a custom landing page I'm hand building (coding myself). To include these plugins, would I do calls somewhere in my custom code for the landing page? What do I necessary have to do? Hopefully this is a little more clear. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Plugins are installed as site level. Not sure what mean with "include plugin in page templates". Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to "include" plugins. Plugins operate, or ***should operate***, by means of the extensive ["hook" system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) built into WordPress core. Once activated, a plugin should not require much else (with a few exceptions for very complicated plugins).

What you need to do is make sure that you are using the appropriate Core functions classes to generate content-- such as `get_header()`, `get_footer()`, `the_content()`, `the_title()`, `WP_Query`, `get_template_part()`. It is a very, very long list.

This related answer might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103644/21376

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply! I wanted to thank you for your answer! I was able to achieve what I wanted to because of it! Cheers!