# Modify a plugin's content

Tags: plugins, hooks

I'm using [Mooberry Book Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mooberry-book-manager/) which has a hook in it's grid

```
mbdb_book_grid_after_link
```

I've created a plug in so that I can show additional content in the grid, it's very basic

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: jw-book-enchance
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );
function addOptions($post_id){
     $post = get_post($post_id);
     echo $post_id;
}
add_filter('mbdb_book_grid_after_link','addOptions');
?>
```

however when I run this it gives me the post ids before the the plugin's content.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the way the hook was implemented or if there is something I'm missing about how to do this.

here is a screenshot [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You don't `echo` content from a filter, you `return` it. You should have:

```
function addOptions($post_id){
     $post = get_post($post_id);
     return $post_id;
}
add_filter('mbdb_book_grid_after_link','addOptions');
```

See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113760/21376

Comment: That resulted in no output. at all

Comment: Then you may have an **action** not a filter, despite your using `add_filter()` instead of `add_action()` as would be correct for an action. If that is the case, the solution is going to be plugin specific and the question most likely off topic. You may not be able to do what you want.

Comment: ok looking at the code in the plugin
do_action('mbdb_book_grid_after_link', $mbdb_bookID, $mbdb_book_title, $image_src, $mbdb_book_grid_cover_height, $c);
so it is an action

Comment: Then you're content is going to come out where the plugin let's it.