# Trying to use WP_Query to display a custom post type

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to use WP_Query in function.php to display a custom post type on a certain page.

I just can't seem to get it to work, can anyone see issues with my code? nothing is output at all and there are apparently no errors.

```
/*** add venues to venue page ***/
add_action( 'woo_post_inside_after', 'venue_loop' );

function venue_loop() {
  if ( is_page(123) ) {
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'tribe_venue',
      'orderby' => 'title', 
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'posts_per_page' => 10
    );

    $venue_posts = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $venue_posts->have_posts() ) { 
      while( $venue_posts->have_posts() ) { 
        $venue_posts->the_post();
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
      }
    }
    return $output;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would be `echo`ing content from an action hook, rather than returning it, and from I can find about this Woo Theme hook that looks to be the case here too.

Try `echo $output;` instead of `return $output;`

See:
[Clarification on filters and hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103641/clarification-on-filters-and-hooks/)
[Difference Between Filter and Action Hooks?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks)

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much, you are correct - just changing that one word makes it work fine :). I will read up on hooks and filters then. Thanks again :)