# How to add a class to the attachment images

Tags: php, functions, images, attachments, editor

When I'm in the Wordpress editor and I add an external image with the 'img' button, my html result wil be like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="image" />
```

How can automatically have a class being added to the img tag?
Like this:

```
<img class="my-img-class" src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="image" />
```

I would like to apply the same principle to the 'Add Media' option.
This output is like this:

```
<a href="mywordpressdomain/image.jpg"><img src="mywordpressdomain/image.jpg" alt="image" width="872" height="867" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-59" /></a>
```

And I want the output to be like this:

```
<a href="mywordpressdomain/image.jpg"><img src="mywordpressdomain/image.jpg" alt="image" width="872" height="867" class="alignnone size-full my-img-class" /></a>
```

I'm new with PHP, so I'm not sure how to this via a filter.
I'm started like this, but I don't know what to do next:

```
function image_tag_class($class, $id, $align, $size) {
    return $align;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class', 'image_tag_class', 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
function image_tag_class($class) {
    $class .= ' my-custom-class';
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class', 'image_tag_class' );
```

in case you wanna know more about actions and hooks.

[Difference Between Filter and Action Hooks?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks)
[add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)
[add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

Comment: thanks, I've tried your function, but no class is added to the img tag when I add an image link in the post editor.

Comment: When you add an image to the post editor from the add media button it's not coming with the 'my-custom-class' css class? Before I send it to you, I've made testes here, and it was working Or you want the class when you have image link?

Comment: Yes sorry it's working, I was in the wrong theme:$
Thank you

Comment: it's however not working when I insert a link via the 'link' button (insert from url) in the post editor. Also, how do I remove the default wordpress class 'wp-image-59' ?

Comment: Note that the class will be added to new images only. It will not be added to old images, because the HTML is already generated in the content editor.