# Redirect customer to login if not logged in when proceeding to checkout

Tags: hooks, redirect, buttons

I'm trying to redirect customers, who are not logged in, when they push the "proceed to checkout button" on my cart page but nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
function custom_redirect_checkout(){
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ){

  wp_redirect( 'https://www.domain.co/login/', 301 );

  exit;
  }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'custom_redirect_checkout' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout` is an action, not a filter.

See http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout/.

For the difference between actions and filters check out this question: [Difference Between Filter and Action Hooks?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks)

Comment: [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) is an alias for add_filter, so this does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to your child's theme functions.php file.

```
function wp_checkout_login_redirect() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in()&& (is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
        wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wp_checkout_login_redirect');
```

Comment: Wouldn't [auth_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/auth_redirect/) be better, because it'll automatically return you to the checkout page when you log in? (which I don't think your code does) And I'm assuming WooCommerce doesn't post to either the cart page or checkout page, else you'd lose the posted data.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect customers to the login page when they are either in the cart or the checkout page, you can use the following code:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/login/' ) ); // Change '/login/' to the URL of your login page
        exit;
    }
} );
```

This code will redirect customers to the login page if they are not logged in and are either in the cart or the checkout page. Replace `'/login/'` with the actual URL of your login page. You can add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file or in a custom plugin.

This is very similar to the answer by @Olowoseun, but my response allows for the option to customize the login URL destination as needed.