# How apply_filters work in WordPress?

Tags: filters

I know that how `do_action` works in WordPress.

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    // Action hook before any output!
    do_action( 'dr_before_get_qod_text' );

    echo "foo and bar";

}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

If I have a similar code, I can display **"ABC"** before displaying **"foo and bar"** using following code.

```
function display_abc() {
   echo "ABC";
}
add_action( 'dr_before_get_qod_text', 'display_abc');
```

---

But I can't understand how `apply_filters` work. Can you please give me a practical example?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? There are many such examples everywhere... Just take a look at docs (Codex) for any native filter (the_content for instance).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clarification on filters and hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103641/clarification-on-filters-and-hooks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference Between Filter and Action Hooks?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the apply_filters() hook is bit confusing at first when you encounter it.
I'll try my best to explain this:

first you need to know that filter hooks allow you to change data before displaying or storing data.

Lets take an example

```
function list_array(){
  $arr_name = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];
  return $arr_name;
}
```

as you can see above function just returns an array and consider this code was in your plugin and you want other developer to modify the default array. That's where `apply_filters()` hook comes in handy

```
function list_array(){
  $arr_name = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];
  $arr_name = apply_filters( 'hook_identifier', $arr_name);
  return $arr_name;
}
```

now the 'hook_identifier' can be used to modify the array values, like

```
function add_extra_val( $arr ){
  $extra_val = ['extraval1','extraval2','extraval3']; //remember you are adding elements to array
  $arr = array_merge($extra_val, $arr);
}
add_filter('hook_identifier', 'add_extra_val');
```

You see the add_extra_val function takes one array ( as every filter hook, ) as an argument and then extra values are added to that array and then returned.

### so what exactly did apply_filters() hook did?

it is calling all the functions ( in this case 'add_extra_val' ) that have been added to the hook ( in this case 'hook_identifier' ) at that point in the code base ( in this case when $arr_name = apply_filters( 'hook_identifier', $arr_name) ).

This is it. hope you understand now.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.. Is this applies for only modify object or arrays? Or are  there more things?

Comment: as I said filter hooks are used to modify data and data can be any valid php data type. I choose array for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Thanks.... Just one question..... Do you know `pre_get_posts `. _This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run. The pre_get_posts action gives developers access to the $query object by reference_ This should be filter as I think? but why it implement as a action

Comment: Visit: https://wpshout.com/practical-uses-pre_get_posts/
for more information.