# Using a filter to change a path

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I know this is probably basic Wordpress coding but how would I achieve this?

> Use the filter “wcvendors_pro_table_display_rows_path” — and return a
> path to the new template file.
> (/plugins/wc-vendors-pro/public/class-wcvendors-pro-table-helper.php
> Line #328.)

Line #328 of plugins/wc-vendors-pro/public/class-wcvendors-pro-table-helper.php is:

```
public function display_rows() {

        include apply_filters( 'wcvendors_pro_table_display_rows_path', 'partials/helpers/table/wcvendors-pro-table-data.php' );

    }
```

I have created a duplicate of wcvendors-pro-table-data.php in my child theme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How apply\_filters work in WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308969/how-apply-filters-work-in-wordpress)

Comment: As a total newbie to Wordpress development it doesn't - I tried using that guide but still don't really know what I am doing...thank for responding though @kero

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you don't understand? The topic of filters and actions is widely covered, as it is core element in WP development. I understand in the beginning it might be difficult to grip - similarly it is difficult for me to help without fully understanding what your problem with the concept is.

Comment: Sorry I will try and explain...the file wcvendors-pro-table-data.php is in a directory that can't be edited without being wiped when the plugin is updated. The developer suggested that I use the filter 'wcvendors_pro_table_display_rows_path' to specific a path to the new file that will be in my child theme folder and hence not be wiped when updated. Using actions and filters is like a minefield and so I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the template you want to use, say `wc-vp-table-rows.php`, put it in your theme, and add the following to your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 
    'wcvendors_pro_table_display_rows_path', 
    fn() => locate_template( 'wc-vp-table-rows.php' )
);
```

[`locate_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) returns a complete path; it also searches in parent and child themes.

Comment: Something to take into account, PHP arrow function, `fn (argument_list) => expr`, is a single line only and is available for **version >= 7.4**, so if you ecnouter any problems with this use a regular anonymous function.